# How to reset and close the Modal on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a Modal with some contents on it. When I click the cancel button, I want to clear and reset the contents of the modal. But the problem I face is that, When I click the cancel button and reopen the modal, the contents still remain on the modal.

I have attached the image of the Modal:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSjy9.png)

The above image is before clicking the cancel button. The below image is after closing the modal and reopening the modal again.

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJzBs.png)

I have attached the code below:

HTML:

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <div id="imagearea" class="imagearea">
      <div class='dynamic_text' style='display:none;'></div>

    <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="fashion.jpg">

    </div>
      <div class="text_container">

        <br>
        <div class="img_text">

        </div>
        <div class="input_tag">
          <span class="right_sec_text">Select a region from the picture</span>
          <div class="error"></div>

          <div class="tags" id ="tags"></div>
          <div class="input_box">
          <input type="text" name="tags" id="name_tag" class="input_textbox">
          <button id="settag" class="btn_settag">Set Tag</button>
          </div>
            <div class="footer_btn">
            <p><button class="btn_success" id="btn_add" value="add areas">Confirm Selection</button>
            <p><button class="btn_cancel" onclick="$('#myModal').hide()">Cancel</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The code for cancel button:

```
    <p><button class="btn_cancel" onclick="$('#myModal').hide()">Cancel</button>
```

Can someone help me fix this problem to close and reset the Modal?

Comment: Did you sort out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `modal` API and pass the `hide` parameter to close the modal

```js
    $('#close').on('click', function() {
       $('#myModal').modal('hide')
    });
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Test modal</button>

    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="myModal" data-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          The modal will not close until clicked on the button<br/>
          The modal will not close until clicked on the button<br/>
          The modal will not close until clicked on the button<br/>
          The modal will not close until clicked on the button<br/>
          The modal will not close until clicked on the button<br/>
          <button class="btn_cancel" id="close">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: @viki Can you show me your code now? You can paste it [here](kopy.io) and share the link

Comment: https://kopy.io/MxMzv    I have attached the code here

Comment: its says an error, " $(...).modal is not a function"

Comment: @viki does it open the modal?

Comment: @viki Why do you have two versions of `jQuery`?

Comment: Depending where I look, it seems you are targeting the wrong button. ``$('btn_cancel').click(function(){`` vs ``$('#btn_cancel').click(function(){`` but you should be targeting ``$('.btn_cancel').click(function(){`` as it is a CLASS not an ID on the button.

Comment: @Dexterians the button has both `ID` and `Class`

Comment: @BasheerKharoti i tried removing one jquery version and still the error appears, "$(...).modal is not a function"

Comment: @viki you need to add the `JS` part of the `bootstrap` as well in order to make it work. Add this link to a new `Script` tag `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: @BasheerKharoti i have attached the code here  https://kopy.io/doGSB . Still the error is there

Comment: @viki - not according to the code in your question: ``<p><button class="btn_cancel" onclick="$('#myModal').hide()">Cancel</button>``

Comment: @viki the error is due to the ordering of the scripts. Just copy this [file](https://kopy.io/AKKca)

Comment: @BasheerKharoti I copied your code , now there is no error displayed in console but , the modal is not closing

Comment: The modal is not closing because you are basically hijacking the modals original functions with this new event listener. You're using Bootstrap - so I suspect you are conflicting listeners. Bootstrap already has ways of handling the close button of the modal. But closing a modal does not CLEAR the values you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @BasheerKharoti did u find any solution for this

Comment: @viki That's the solution I already answered. There's something wrong with your code not with the modal right now. You can run my answer and check it

Answer (score 0):

As part of your cancel function you could add;

`$("#reset").click()` or `$(".reset").click()`

^ You'd have the find the class or ID of that reset button, I can't see it in your code. Or just clear the values of the fields as part of the cancel button function.

I also notice a typo in your JavaScript. You forgot to specify the class;

```
  $('.btn_cancel').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
  $(this).removeData('modal');
  });
  });
```

You had `$('btn_cancel').click(function(){...`

Comment: Can you paste a working demonstration on CodePen or JSFiddle - the reason it's not closing is because you probably now have 2 functions listening to the button click of the close button or your scripts are ordered improperly - you may also even be using incorrect functions; or you are not targeting correctly. So it would be good to see Fiddle or Pen to better diagnose your issue so that we can see the console logs etc.

Comment: Can you please show me how to solve this, I cannot understand what you have commented about the bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap already has modal support - you don't need to add additional javascript to handle the close button. Read the documentation, ensure you structure your Bootstrap Modal HTML according to the guide/template - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ - also see - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: I have edited my code, I removed the Javascript code for closing the modal and i used it directly on html tag. Now the modal closes, but when i reopen the modal the contents are still there, they dont get reset

Comment: Yes, as per my comment - you will need to now create a function that clears the modal when it's closed. Example;

``$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    //do stuff when a modal is closed
});``

- or in your example, it would likely be something like;

``$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.modal-body input').val('')
});``

Comment: Or try;

``$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeData();
});``